# Return same html at multiple place without repeating same component selector angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular7

I have a scenario and I think, Many of the angular developers will have face this scenario. 
I have multiple tiles when data is available, then they show the data. But when data is not available, then We have to show a common message like this.

[image]

**These tiles are not generated using *ngfor. Now, If I create a common component for this (which have HTML - No data available), I will have to add this component selector in all my tiles. Is there any better way to do this?
Using directives (I know, directives do not have HTML.) 
Or any other concept which I am missing. Or repeating common component selector is the only solution?**

Comment: If you don't want to use `*ngFor` you could either create your own structural directive to display another template if the data isn't here yet, or you could use `*ngIf=data; else template` (on each element) and then define a template in your html like so `<ng-template  #template>No data available</ng-template>`

Comment: Can you show me an example to do this using a custom structural directive? *ngIf also, I want to avoid for every tile.  Custome structure directive is something, I am looking for.

Comment: @Nimishgoel [here you go](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives)

Comment: yeah, custom structure directive, I know, but that does not return any HTML, How can we use it in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.
Make a array for tiles and set data.

```
tiles: Array<any> = [
    {
        title: 'Channel',
        data: []
    },
    {
        title: 'Campaign',
        data: []
    },
    {
        title: 'Region',
        data: []
    },
    {
        title: 'Product',
        data: []
    },
];
```

Use `*ngFor` for show tiles inside HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let tile of tiles">
    <tile-component [tileData]="tile"><tile-component>
</div>
```

Inside tile component you need to do this;

import Input for get input data from parent component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Input() tileData;
```

Do this in your tile component html

```
<h4>{{tileData['title']}}<h4>

<p *ngIf="tileData['data'].length == 0">No data available</p>
```

Comment: They all are different tiles. Can not go with ngfor. Each and every tile is having different format data.  I mentioned in the question also.

Comment: Then repeating component is only the way for achieving this.